# Is there any equivalent of Type.IsInterface or IsClass in Windows Store .NET?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I can't find anything. I want to check if type is not interface.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On WinRT, most reflection methods are accessible through [`TypeInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can get a type's `TypeInfo` through the [`GetTypeInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.introspectionextensions.gettypeinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method, available under the `System.Reflection` namespace

```
typeof(string).GetTypeInfo().IsInterface
```

Comment: This seems to be true for .NET Core as well

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: There is a NuGet package providing extension methods for Type class - https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.TypeExtensions